# How to call completionBlock in URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm trying to learn how to use Rest API. I want to use Github API to login from iPhone first.

Here is my model (it's not completed yet):

```
mutating func gettingAceess(completionBlock: @escaping (_ data : Data?, _ response : URLResponse?, _ error : Error?) -> Void ) throws {
    guard username != "", password != "" else {
        throw loginError.emptyUsernameOrPassword
    }

    let loginString = "\(self.username):\(self.password)"
    let resourceUrl = "https://\(loginString)@api.github.com"
    guard let loggingUrl = URL(string: resourceUrl) else {fatalError()}

    let logging = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: loggingUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("\(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }

    logging.resume()
}
```

In the controller, I want when user taps the login button, getting access function should be called.

```
@IBAction func pressLoginBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let username = usernameInput.text,  let password = passwordInput.text {
        var logginInformation = LogginReguest(username: username, password: password)
        do {
            try logginInformation.gettingAceess(completionBlock: ...)
        } catch {
  }
```

In the code front of the `try`, I don't know what I should write. Can anyone help me? Or I am doing the whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. First of all check for empty text fields already before calling the asynchronous task.

Secondly it's bad practice to make a function `throws` which contains an asynchronous task, in the completion block return the received data or the error.

This is an example with the `Result` struct returning the received `Data` as string or the error.

```
mutating func gettingAccess(completionBlock: @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void)
{
    let loginString = "\(self.username):\(self.password)"
    let resourceUrl = "https://\(loginString)@api.github.com"
    guard let loggingUrl = URL(string: resourceUrl) else {fatalError()}

    let logging = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: loggingUrl) { (data, _, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
        } else {
            let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
            completion(.success(string))
        }
    }

    logging.resume()
}
```

---

```
@IBAction func pressLoginBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard usernameInput.hasText, passwordInput.hasText else { 
       // show an alert
       return
    }
    let logginInformation = LogginReguest(username: usernameInput.text!, password: passwordInput.text!)
    logginInformation.gettingAccess { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let string): print(string)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)

        }
    } 
  }
```

Side note:

Please look for contemporary tutorials. The syntax `(_ data : Data?, _ response : URLResponse?, _ error : Error?)` with parameter labels and underscores is Swift 2 legacy syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
  // if completion block is last argument; you can use trailing syntax
  try logginInformation.gettingAceess() { (data, response, error) in
     // as your completion block have this signature
     // completionBlock: @escaping (_ data : Data?, _ response : URLResponse?, _ error : Error?) -> Void)

  }
} catch {
```

You will need to update `gettingAceess` method also.

```
let logging = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: loggingUrl) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
     print("\(String(describing: error))")
   }
   // This line passes this completion block to caller who can read it
   completion(data, response, error)
}
```

The above detail was how you will get completion block working in your example. The suggestion would be not to pass the `URLSession` completion block directly; rather process it.

```
enum NKError: Error {
  case networkError
}

func gettingAceess(completionBlock: @escaping (Result<[String: Any], NKError>) -> Void ) {
  let logging = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: loggingUrl) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print("\(String(describing: error))")
      completion(.failure(NKError.networkError))
    }

    // Now I can check for status or data
    if let data = data {
      // parse the result and then return
      if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
        completion(.success(json))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, I am trying to pass the `error` or `json` to caller.

Comment: Your `gettingAceess` method cannot work (it doesn't even compile regardless of the typos). It's impossible to `throw` an error in a completion block.

Comment: @vadian I should have compiled it before posting. Now the post is updated and removed the typos.